# why dapper ORM is so fast by comparing Entity Framework and ADO.NET?

Tags: performance, ado.net, entity-framework-6, compare, dapper

Please mention the reason of Fast execution of dapper ORM by comparing Entity Framework and ADO.NET. I got the reference for comparison from the link [dapper vs entity framework](https://dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2014/05/01/speed-comparison-dapper-vs-entity-framework/)

Comment: First, nothing can be faster than ADO.NET because all frameworks use ADO.NET internally. Second, you are comparing apples and oranges, because Dapper is *micro* ORM while EF is full ORM, hence supports much complex scenarios, which of course have asociated overhead. Dapper requires SQL knowledge, EF - does not. etc.

Comment: I have gone through this link https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/dapper-vs-entity-framework-vs-ado-net-performance-benchmarking/. it says dapper is faster than ADO.NET. Why dapper is so fast than ADO.NET even though dapper is written over ADO.NET?

Comment: The test is unfair because it's using `DataTable` and `DataAdapter`.

Comment: Have you run your own tests on your own data? Even though I'm rooting for Dapper here, EF have made *really good* improvements over the last few versions.

Comment: Dapper is faster than EF Core, which is faster than EF, all on latest versions, on my recent tests for my app. But EF Core has major improvements and it _really_ fast indeed.

Comment: @IvanStoev I kind of disagree on EF being a "full ORM" in comparison to Dapper. Though Dapper does indeed have a lot smaller feature set, it's in no way less of an ORM than Entity Framework. They both do Object-Relational Mapping. It's just that Entity Framework does a ton more - a lot of it being outside the bounds of what's expected from an ORM.

Comment: At the end of the day, IDataReader is "practically" your fastest.  This is what any testing should be used against, not DataSet hydration.  To repeat what others have said, dapper cannot be faster than ado.net.  in fact, dapper is a collection of extension methods... quote from GitHub: Dapper is a NuGet library that you can add in to your project that will extend your IDbConnection interface.

Answer (score 1):

It can never happen that Dapper is much faster than ADO.Net. Period!

We know that Dapper team has written an advance mechanism via IL to just speed-up the process, but still it is running on top of ADO.Net. They are only abstracting the ADO.Net and processed everything on top of it by converting the actual data (rows) back to the object models (POCO or DTO), and that would add additional time doing it.

I think everyone must understand the separation of concern of the ADO.Net layer from any other ORM available on this world.

Or else or unless, the Dapper team will write their own version of DbDataReader, then, there could be a possibility that they are much faster, but never ever it will happen until they do it.

With EF, there is no question that Dapper is much faster than it as they are the most lightweight ORM right now that is available.

IMHO

Comment: They are more lightweight as they have the most minimum lines of code being processed during the runtime.